# Normalization of functions in function space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, conventions, normalization

It is a well know question, be the function space $L_{2}(-\infty,\infty)$, evidently the eigenfunctions of $$i\frac{d}{dx}, X$$ are $$f = Ae^{-i \lambda x}, g=B \delta (x-\lambda)$$ respectively.

Evidently again, it is not normalized in such function space. In order to orthonormalize both, we can do it:
$$\int f^{*}_{\lambda}f_{\mu} = |A|^{2}2\pi\delta(\lambda-\mu)$$
$$\int g^{*}_{\lambda}g_{\mu} = |B|^{2}\delta(\lambda-\mu)$$

Til here all is ok, but so, it is assumed that:

$$<f_{\lambda}|f_{\mu}> = \delta(\lambda-\mu), f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e^{-i\lambda x}}$$
$$<g_{\lambda}|g_{\mu}> = \delta(\lambda-\mu), g = \delta(x-\lambda)$$

I am missing this last step, to be honest, i am not sure how was found B, A. Not just, what i understood is that here, the "module <f|f>" is actually infinity, and not one, is it?

Comment: What do you understand by $\delta(\lambda-\mu)$?

Comment: If lambda equals mu, it is infinity, otherwise, zero